# eclipse indent tabs with spaces not working

Tags: eclipse, autoindent

I have the settings for this done correctly.

[image]
However for certain cases, like when I declare or initialize an anonymous class, and eclipse puts out auto-generated code, all of that is still tab-spaced. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Which editor in Eclipse are you actually using, though? Formatting rules might case an editor to ignore this preference.

Comment: normal java editor - eclipse luna

Answer (score 3):

For the Java Editor, it's controlled with/by the Java Formatter preferences.
[image: Java Editor Typing preferences]
[image: Relevant section of the Formatter profile]

Comment: I'm not sure why there would be a general offer of 'insert spaces for tabs' yet not respect it.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't modify the built-in profile, so first I had to create my own. Luckily, you can copy a built-in profile and then customize it.